# Being frugal about Facebook requests

Tags: android, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

I'm designing a networking app similar to a social networking app.
First, the user has to login in with Facebook, then he can join an "event".
To implement these features, I've created a REST API which handles all the requests from the user on the front-end.

All around the app, the user has to make numerous requests to the API.
And since I wanted to make all my requests to the server completely secure, I always retrieve the UID and Access Token before making any connexion to the server. So that I can, on the server-side, easily reject requests from the user if his access token is not valid (I check w/ the FB Graph API).

**Summary** : *When making every request, we retrieve UID and Access Token, then send it with the request to the server. The server check on his side if the token associated to UID is valid or not, and then respond.*

My issue is simple, all of these requests are **very** intensive networking-wise.
I have to wait at least 3-4 seconds when making every single request (which can be as small as a vote on a post).

How can I be frugal with this authentication design without compromising the security of my app, knowing that the delay is mainly caused by the facebook calls inside the app ?

If you have any suggestions, please feel free to respond, also don't avoid criticizing **any** of the design choices stated above.
I'm always open to constructive criticism.

Thank you :).